# Fill the data to Grid

Tags: c#, sql

simply i want to know how to fill data to grid by using C#
data Source : MS SQL2012
Language    : C#

Without Object inserting **just C# code**. how to do any one can support to me,still am beginner for C#

Comment: The process is more or less automatic in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
 string select = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
 Connection c = new Connection();
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c.con); //c.con is the connection string

 SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; 
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```